# Upgrade went wrong, laptop essentially 'bricked'

Tags: upgrade, data-recovery

I have an old netbook I was trying to upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10.

Ubuntu was in the process of upgrading when everything completely froze.  I left it sit for an hour but it would not respond to anything.

So I powered down the machine and it didn't have the necessary files to run Ubuntu.  I went to the terminal and it told me to put in some command that I can not remember to 'rebuild' something.

That takes me to now, when I turn on the laptop it comes up with a screen `GNU GRUB version 1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3.3` and has a bunch of options such as:

1. Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-32-generic
2. Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-32-generic (recover mode)

etc. (there are like 15 of these with different numbers after 2.6.35 and the word 'generic'.

It doesn't seem to matter what I pick, it will go to the "Ubuntu" loading screen with the colored dots but then every time it will freeze and I have to reboot to the same thing.  I can't seem to get a terminal prompt anywhere either.

Comment: I think a clean install would be a good idea, 10.10 is not supported anyway.

Comment: Do you have data that you need to recover from this install, or do you just need the netbook to work again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading an old netbook, currently running **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS**, then you should first test with **12.04 LTS** from a USB device. If this works, then try a *clean install*.

If your netbook in now non-responsive, then do try a fresh install of **12.04 LTS**.

I have successfully run both **10.04 LTS** and **12.04 LTS** on an 'old' HP Mini netbook - with Atom processor and 1GB RAM.

---

**NOTE:**

- *You should always **backup** any data, documents, and important settings before attempting an upgrade. You should also be fully **updated**, on the current version.*
- *You could have upgraded, directly from **10.04 LTS** to **12.04 LTS**, but I would **not** personally recommend this.*
- *As noted by **@mikewhatever**, you should **not** be attempting to use **10.10** (or **11.04**) ..*

Answer (score 0):

Your netbook is not bricked. I too have an old netbook. As most people have found out they are very under-powered for windows, but not for Linux.

So I installed Debian 6 (server install) and have turned it into a printer and file server. Does the job without a flinch and I control it through SSH.